# FTP MDTM with Folders

Tags: iis-6, ftp

I'm running FileZilla 3.6.0.1 client

Windows Server 2003 ftp server

mdtm file works 
but it fails with folders 
I tried :

> mdtm . mdtm \folder mdtm /

can't figure how to get the time stamp of a folder 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla and IIS6 don't support it for files

According to RFC 3659, MDTM is only specified for files which may be retrieved
[Answer on FileZilla Forums](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=28161&p=104935#p104935)